# How to get the relationship data from casted toArray Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to get the data without using eager loading in a Eloquent Model but I needed to cast it into Array to use in some part of the code.
In order words, I wanna just get the data like this example:

```php
$invoice->invoice_type_id->name;
```

Since it's an array what I'm writing is: `nfe['invoice_type_id']['name']`

But I'm getting this error (because it's an array):

```php
Trying to get property of non object
```

So, my query is:

```php
Invoice::query()->where('order_id', $order_id)->get()->toArray();
```

And my model I already have the relationship declared:

```php
public function invoiceType()
{
   return $this->belongsTo(InvoiceType::class);
}
```

Comment: stop calling `toArray` then ... call `toArray` on this Collection only when you need it as an array ..... and you should be eager loading that relationship otherwise you will have a N+1 issue ... if your relationship is `invoiceType` why are you trying to access `invoice_type_id` as though it will return an object?

Comment: It's because invoice_type_id is a column that I have in Invoice table and is a relationship with invoice type table.

Comment: that is a regular attribute it isnt a relationship, why would it return an object that would have a name property? if you want to access the relationship you would have to use the dynamic property for the relationship

Comment: it's a regular attribute but it means in other table a reference for a name of this invoiceType. So, if it's 1, then it means "x" and if it's 2, then it means "y".

Comment: but its not an OBJECT ... its not the relationship, it is just the 'id' field which would be scalar variable which is not an object (doesn't have properties) `Trying to get property of non object`

Comment: The proper relationship call would be `$invoice->invoice_type->name;`, no id on it